# ggplot: geom_line/geom_path with two attributes

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, line-plot

I would like to plot simple lines using `geom_line()` or `geom_path()` with linetype and color according to two grouping variables. The following code does not execute but should show what I mean:

```
df_wide <- data.frame(
  attribute_1 = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
  attribute_2 = c("C", "C", "D", "D"),
  t1 = c(2, 4, NA, NA),
  t2 = c(1, 2, 3, 5),
  t3 = c(5, 2, 4, 1))

df_long <- df_wide %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 3:5, values_to = "value", names_to = "time") %>% 
  mutate(time = substr(time, 2, 2))

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = attribute_1, color = attribute_2))
```

I can switch to using `geom_path()` and drop the linetype to get almost what I want...

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_path(aes(group = attribute_1, color = attribute_2))
```

... but replacing `group = attribute_1` by `linetype = attribute_1` results in an error message.
What is the proper way to achieve both groupings?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your `time` column isn't a numeric. Convert to a numeric and your code should work fine:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

df_long <- df_wide %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 3:5, values_to = "value", names_to = "time") %>%
  mutate(
    time = substr(time, 2, 2),
    time = as.numeric(time)
  )

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = attribute_1, color = attribute_2)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(df_long$time))
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_line()`).
```

[image]

Comment: As simple as that! Thanks a lot for your quick and helpful answer!